# Lucene.net 3.0.5 - Reading uncommited changes, possible?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I'm indexing a sequence of documents with the IndexWriter and commiting the changes at the end of the iteration.

However, halfway the iteration I would like to "query" the uncommitted changes using an IndexSearcher. Is this possible with the current version of Lucene.Net ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you need a so-called *near real-time reader* do do that. You open such a reader by calling the [`IndexWriter.GetReader`](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d2/d1d/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_index_1_1_index_writer.html#a57044cd06b7b2b00bb33a08ad666d4c5) function:

> returns a readonly reader, covering all committed as well as un-committed changes to the index. This provides "near real-time" searching, in that changes made during an `IndexWriter` session can be quickly made available for searching without closing the writer nor calling `Commit()`.

See the relevant [blog post](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/06/lucenes-near-real-time-search-is-fast.html). It's for Java but applies to the .NET version as well.